# room android title is not filled in the list on StartFragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I get the table and complete the title in the list on the start page, but the text not updated for some reason, what could be the problem?

I have a table:

```
    @Entity(tableName = "Note_table")
class NoteModel (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo
    var title: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo
    var description: String = ""
        ) : Serializable
```

I have RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_margin="1dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="title"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

and in the class NoteAdapte, i complete in the title (here -   binding.itemTitle.text = listNote[position].title), but in the activity I get itemTitle.text = title:

```
class NoteAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.NoteViewHolder>() {
    lateinit var binding: ItemLayoutBinding
    var listNote = emptyList<NoteModel>()

    class NoteViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteViewHolder {
        binding = ItemLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
       val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
       return NoteViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteViewHolder, position: Int) {
        binding.itemTitle.text = listNote[position].title

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
     return listNote.size
    }
    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun setList(list: List<NoteModel>){
        listNote = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: NoteViewHolder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            StartFragment.clickNote(listNote[holder.adapterPosition])
        }
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: NoteViewHolder) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(null)
    }
}
```

link to Git: https://github.com/Avdors/RoomLesson.git

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWwrR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to have a ItemLayoutBinding per item in your Adapter.
Here you are not.

First change the declaration of the NoteViewHolder class.

```kotlin
class NoteViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val binding: ItemLayoutBinding
        init {
            binding = ItemLayoutBinding.bind(view)
        }
    }
```

The onCreateViewHolder method become :

```kotlin
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteViewHolder {
       val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
       return NoteViewHolder(view)
    }
```

And the onBindViewHolder become:

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.itemTitle.text = listNote[position].title
    }
```